# Weak references inside a block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using an `NSOperationQueue` and queuing up `NSOperationBlocks`. Now, blocks have a strong reference to any instances in the block, and the calling object also has a strong hold on the block, so it has been advised to do something like the following:

```
__weak Cell *weakSelf = self;
NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        UIImage *image = /* render some image */
        /* what if by the time I get here self no longer exists? */
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [weakSelf setImageViewImage:image];
        }];
    }];
    [self.renderQueue addOperation:op];
```

So, my question is, let's say that by the time the image finishes rendering and that line comes back, the `Cell` object no longer exists (it has been deallocated, possibly due to cell reuse, which is a bit difficult to formalize). When I go to access `[weakSelf setImageViewImage:]`, will that cause a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error?

Currently I'm trying to trace what the cause of my problem is, and I'm thinking it might have something to do with this.

Comment: Does the cell have a strong ref to renderQueue? Does anything else have a strong ref to renderQueue? If you want to trace the cause of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, use an interactive debugger or Instruments.

Comment: The weak reference should be unneccessary here. Assuming ARC, `op` is going to be released at the end of whatever method this code is in, (it's also retained/released by the operation queue, but that's irrelevant at the moment). There would only be a retain cycle if you were relying on `self`'s `dealloc` to release the Block, i.e., you were storing it in an ivar. That's not the case here, and so you don't need to worry about the Block retaining `self`.

Comment: So when does the operation queue release the item? After it has completed executing, automatically? Or must I manually release the block? I am using ARC.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, `__weak` is a zeroing weak reference. What this means is that during your operation, `self` may indeed be deallocated, but all weak references to it (namely `weakSelf`) will be zeroed out. This means that `[weakSelf setImageViewImage:image]` is just sending a message to `nil`, which is safe; or, at least, it shouldn't cause an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. (Incidentally, if you had qualified `weakSelf` as `__unsafe_unretained`, you might end up sending messages to a freed object.)

So, I doubt that sending a message to a `__weak` reference is causing a crash. If you want to ensure that `self` survives for the length of your operation, you can get a strong reference to the weak one in the block scope:

```
__weak Cell *weakSelf = self;

NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    Cell *strongSelf = weakSelf; // object pointers are implicitly __strong
    // strongSelf will survive the duration of this operation.
    // carry on.
}];
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't use weak, you're creating a retain cycle, but the cycle will be broken as soon as the blocks have finished executing.  I probably wouldn't bother using weak here.

Anyway, you can send any message to `nil`, and it will be ignored.  So if the `weakSelf` variable gets set to `nil` because the `Cell` object is deallocated, the `setImageViewImage:` message will silently do nothing.  It won't crash.

Since you mention cell reuse, I presume your `Cell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.  In that case, your example code has a serious problem.  `UITableViewCell`s normally don't get deallocated.  They get put on the cell reuse queue.  So your `weakSelf` variable will not get zeroed, because a weak reference only get zeroed when the object is actually deallocated.

By the time the `[weakSelf setImageViewImage:image]` line gets run, the cell may have been reused to represent a different row in your table, and you're putting the wrong image in the cell.  You should move your image-rendering code out of the `Cell` class, into your table view's datasource class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Cell *cell = // get a cell...

    [self startLoadingImageForIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)startLoadingImageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        UIImage *image = [self renderImageForIndexPath:indexPath];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            Cell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [cell setImageViewImage:image];
        });
    }];
    [self.renderQueue addOperation:op];
}
```

Comment: Wait, what do you mean self doesn't retain the operation queue? It is a strong property in my class. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Oops. You're right, it does retain renderQueue.  But it's a short-lived cycle, automatically broken as soon as the blocks have finished executing.

Comment: What if I was storing the block operations in my own dictionary that is strongly held by the data source, so that I can retrieve and cancel operations as necessary. How would this change things?

Comment: Then you should remove that entry from the dictionary in the same block the sends the `setImageViewImage:` message, to break the retain cycle and free up memory.

Comment: So in your code, calling [self.tableView cellRowRow:] in the block doesn't lead to a retain cycle?

Comment: The cycle is broken as soon as the blocks finish executing.

Comment: @robmayoff, hi, I just dropped by your answer, and I'd like to give my input on the matter. I think that managing the loading of the image in the view controller is a bit problematic, as it moves logic from the cell to the controller. A better solution, IMHO, would be to cancel the request in prepareForReuse.  This would also fix problems relating to network latency. What do you think? Thanks