# Weak references in blocks and retain cycles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603284/weak-references-inside-a-block), I asked about the following code and retain cycles:

```
__weak Cell *weakSelf = self;
NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        UIImage *image = /* render some image */
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [weakSelf setImageViewImage:image];
        }];
    }];
    [self.renderQueue addOperation:op];
```

All answers state that using a weak reference here was not necessary, since this code does not result in a retain cycle. However, while experimenting with some more code, the following does result in a retain cycle (if I don't use a weak reference, the current view controller is not deallocated)

```
    //__weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;
    MBItem *close = [[MBItem alloc] initWithBlock:^{
        [self dismissModalWithDefaultAnimation:NO];
    }];
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:close, nil];
    [self.childObject setItems:items];
```

Why would the second one result in a retain cycle but not the first one?

Comment: The keyword is "Retain CYCLE". As in, I retain you and you retain me, so who lets go first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your old code creates this retain cycle **if you don't use `__weak`**:

- `(NSBlockOperation *)op` retains the outer block
- The outer block retains `self` (if you're not using `__weak`)
- `self` retains `(NSOperationQueue *)renderQueue`
- `(NSOperationQueue *)renderQueue` retains `(NSBlockOperation *)op`

None of the objects in that cycle can be deallocated unless one of those links is broken.  But the code you showed us **does** break the retain cycle. When `op` finishes executing, `renderQueue` releases it, breaking the retain cycle.

I suspect that your new code creates this retain cycle:

- `(MBItem *)close` retains the block
- The block retains `self`
- `self` retains `childObject`
- `childObject` retains `(NSMutableArray *)items`
- `(NSMutableArray *)items` retains `(MBItem *)close`

If nothing happens to break one of those links, none of the objects in the cycle can be deallocated.  You haven't shown us any code that breaks the retain cycle.  If there is no event that explicitly breaks it (for example by clearing out `childObject.items`), then you need to use `__weak` to break the retain cycle.

Answer (score 8):

I can't tell you the reason for the retain-cycle in your second example, because I don't know `MBItem`, but there are two different usage patterns with blocks.

If you expect your block to execute in any case, then you can just use `self` in the block:

```
[startSomeOperationWithCompletionBlock:^{
    [self doSomeThing];
}];
```

The block retains a reference to `self`, so that `self` is not deallocated before the block is executed. But after the block has executed, this reference (and the retain cycle) is gone.

If you possibly want that `self` is deallocated **before** the block has executed,
or if it is possible that the block will not be called at all,
then you have to use a weak reference and check the value inside the block:

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
[startSomeOperationWithCompletionBlock:^{
    MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf doSomeThing];
    }
}];
```

The block does not retain `self` in this case, so that `self` can be deallocated. In that case, `weakSelf` is set to `nil` automatically. Therefore, if the block is executed finally, you have to check first if `weakSelf` is still valid. (Or you can just use it, because sending messages to `nil` is a no-op.)

Assigning a strong reference `strongSelf` inside the block prevents `self` from being deallocated while the block is executing.

Comment: What if the block is executed, but it is still being held in some array, so that it can be used again? I'm guessing self wouldn't be deallocated here right, until the array is cleared?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what @robmayoff has described in his answer.

Comment: Creating a strong reference to a weak (or in my case __unsafe_unretained) pointer within the block solved a similar issue I was having where the class was deallocated mid execution of block. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR block makes strong reference to only strong references used inside it? I cant understand how passing weakSelf inside block prevents retain cycle, while if I add either strongSelf or weakSelf inside an NSArray which is strong property in 'self', causes a retain cycle.